# How to retrieve JSON array value to PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am having a hard time getting the value of an array in JSON to php.

Here is the JSON format I'm trying to retrieve:

```
{
 "products": [
  {
   "product_id": 18647,
   "model_code": "CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN"
  }
  {
   "product_id": 14343,
   "model_code": "CDEP-Q123-Blue-3GEN"
  }
 ]
}
```

and I'm trying to retrieve it like this but to no avail:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
        foreach($response as $res)
        {
            print $res->products->product_id;
        }
```

It works though if I'm only trying to input a singl output:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
print $response['products'][0]['product_id'];
```

So, can anyone help me how to properly retrieve JSON value to php?

Comment: The $response variable will be an associative array not an object.

Comment: use print $response->products[0]->product_id

Comment: http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%7B%0D%0A+%22products%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A+++%22product_id%22%3A+18647%2C%0D%0A+++%22model_code%22%3A+%22CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN%22%0D%0A++%7D%2C%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A+++%22product_id%22%3A+14343%2C%0D%0A+++%22model_code%22%3A+%22CDEP-Q123-Blue-3GEN%22%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A+%5D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: the $response variable will not an object . it is array. or json_decode($json_response, false); use this syntax.

Comment: Apart from what is all ready said, In your two examples you are using two completely different methods to access the data, If one of them doesn't work and the other does, why not use the one at works?

Comment: json is not in appropriate format .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data you have missed the `,` between the two array. It should be

```
{
 "products": [
  {
   "product_id": 18647,
   "model_code": "CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN"
  },
  {
   "product_id": 14343,
   "model_code": "CDEP-Q123-Blue-3GEN"
  }
 ]
}
```

and another problem is you are accessing the array as an object , as you are decoding the JSON data as below it returns an array :

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

it will return array.

```
$response = json_decode($ds, true);
```

try accessing value as below:

```
foreach($response['products'] as $res)
{
    print $res['product_id'];
}
```

for more detail check out the first example provided here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON format code has an small error, there should be ',' after following section.

```
 {    
    "product_id": 18647,   
    "model_code": "CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN"  
 },
```

Please check following code:

```
{
 "products": [
  {
   "product_id": 18647,
   "model_code": "CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN"
  },
  {
   "product_id": 14343,
   "model_code": "CDEP-Q123-Blue-3GEN"
  }
 ]
}
```

You can also check your JSON code on http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$response = json_decode('{
 "products": [
  {
   "product_id": 18647,
   "model_code": "CVADA-M702-Black-2GEN"
  },
  {
   "product_id": 14343,
   "model_code": "CDEP-Q123-Blue-3GEN"
  }
 ]
}');

foreach ($response->products as $res) {
    echo $res->product_id;
}
```